# How do I stop some notifications but keep text notifications?

Tags: notifications

I have a Samsung galaxy s2 and I treats all notifications as the same. I want text notifications, but I want to stop the game notifications. I find nothing in the apps, or the system to stop this. Is there a way, or an app I can use to do this? I looked at the notification off app and it isn't compatible with my phone.

Comment: I don't know if this feature exists on your phone, but try open the app info of your game from the Android Settings > Apps, and see if there's a checkbox "Show notifications".

Comment: That option isn't there. I looked.

Comment: Its version 4.0.4.

Comment: So, am i out of luck?